# Retain asp label value

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp label whose text is changed dynamically in a web page. I have a button. When I click the button I have to retain the text of the label but instead the value is being set to initial value due to postback. Can anyone help me to figure out how to retain the text of the label. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code

```
<asp:Label ID="lblRate" runat="server" Text="" ></asp:Label>
```

Here is where i am changing the label

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function Decide(option) {
                var temp = "";
                document.getElementById('<%=lblRate.ClientID%>').innerText = "";
                if (option == 1) {
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating1.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating2.ClientID%>').className = "Empty";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating3.ClientID%>').className = "Empty";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating4.ClientID%>').className = "Empty";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating5.ClientID%>').className = "Empty";
                    temp = "1";
                }
                if (option == 2) {
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating1.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating2.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating3.ClientID%>').className = "Empty";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating4.ClientID%>').className = "Empty";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating5.ClientID%>').className = "Empty";
                    temp = "2";

                }
                if (option == 3) {
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating1.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating2.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating3.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating4.ClientID%>').className = "Empty";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating5.ClientID%>').className = "Empty";
                    temp = "3";
                }
                if (option == 4) {
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating1.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating2.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating3.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating4.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating5.ClientID%>').className = "Empty";
                    temp = "4";
                }
                if (option == 5) {
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating1.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating2.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating3.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating4.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    document.getElementById('<%=Rating5.ClientID%>').className = "Filled";
                    temp = "5";
                }
                document.getElementById('<%=lblRate.ClientID%>').innerText = temp;

                return false;
            }
</script>
```

Here is the button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnRatingSubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="btnRatingSubmit"/>
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Show the code, so that we can help you.

Comment: This link solved my problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907112/how-to-maintain-the-value-of-label-after-postback-in-asp-net

Comment: ok. So you should delete this wuestion